# Specificity for input[type="text"]

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

How can I add specifity to something that reads:

```
input[type="text"] { color:red }
```

I want something like:

```
#my_id input[type="text"] { color:red }
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
input[type="text"]#my_id { color:red }
```

[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d7r48/)

Answer (score 1):

When you use an id **and don't want to address a child node** you can omit any other parts, a id must be unique so far you can use just:

```
#my_id { color:red }
```

Comment: That's not true.  Elements with IDs can have children.

Comment: Yes however in terms of overriding CSS rules specificity matters.

Comment: You both are right. I understood the question in another way. I understood the it as specifiying it more and not for specifying children.

Comment: @Marcel that was the reason why I wrote that can be omitted